# jquery find previous url not working with browser back button clicked

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using rails devise for user sign in.

for example lets say i'm now in page a

```
 localhost:3000/a
```

Now i click link and move to page b

```
localhost:3000/b
```

Now i sign in and go to dashboard

```
localhost:3000/dashboard
```

Now i click browser back button, i move to /b page, user not signed in.In browser console i tried

```
window.referrer
```

output:

```
localhost:3000/a
```

expected output was /dashboard.

Comment: for `window.referer` to work like this you need to be clicking and navigating pages AFAIK.

Comment: clicking link is not possible here

Comment: it is not possible to find this way.. best way is to either store it is a different header and get the information.